# UITextfield textfieldchange event not fired

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, uitextfield

I have outlet the connection of UITextField and written this code

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   [txtName addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

}

-(void)textFieldDidChange :(UITextField *)theTextField{
NSLog(@"Text changed");
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
if(textField==txtName)
    {
          [self.view endEditing:YES];
[self performSelector:@selector(ShowNames) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
return NO;
}
return YES;

}
```

But `-(void)textFieldDidChange :(UITextField *)theTextField{` is not fired 
Couldn't understand where Am I going wrong

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: please use - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string

Comment: @Honey, I posted the answer below, but you're IF statement in `-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` is returning the wrong values. Swap your `return NO` with `return YES` and vice versa. See my answer below with the whole method.

Comment: @Honey, any luck? Did my answer below help?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the code method

```
-(void)textFieldDidChange :(UITextField *)theTextField{
NSLog(@"Text changed");
}
```

with

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
```

Comment: Even "shouldChangeCharactersInRange" is not called. But when I comment out "textFieldShouldBeginEditing" then its called

Answer (score 0):

If you want to UITextField events you should use `UITextFieldDelegate`

In your .h file adopt `UITextFieldDelegate`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
```

and then in your .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
     [_txtName setDelegate:self];
}
```

Let me know if you have any issues

Comment: I have done the same , -(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField is getting called , but not -(void)textFieldDidChange :(UITextField *)theTextField{
When I comment out " textFieldShouldBeginEditing" then "textFieldDidChange" is called. Let me know where Im going wrong

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea, but your problem is within your `-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` method.

Right now, before editing this method is called, and if the method returns NO, then the `-(void)textFieldDidChange :(UITextField *)theTextField` method will *not* be called.

Your if statement tests to see if the textField that should start editing is the same as txtName. If it does you are returning *NO* instead of *YES*. I think you just need to swap your NO's and YES's and you'll be golden.

Try this:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(textField==txtName)
    {
          [self.view endEditing:YES];
          [self performSelector:@selector(ShowNames) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
          return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```